# What do the parameters of DBpedia Spotlight mean?

Tags: ontology, dbpedia, linked-data, spotlight-dbpedia

I am interested in using DBpedia Spotlight. However, we need to insert a value to the two parameters **confidence** and **support**. What do these two parameters really mean?

I want to identify the significant, prominent n-grams in the text. In that case, what is the **usual recommendation for confidence and support parameters** (**rule of thumb**)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you ask **DBpedia Spotlight** to annotate text (finding entities/topics), it searches for n-grams that have URIs in DBpedia (n-grams that are Wikipedia titles). Those n-grams are called DBpedia resources.

**Support:** this is the *Resource Prominence* parameter, it helps you to ignore unimportant or uninformative resources. When you set a value X to it, this means **resources that have a number of Wikipedia in-links smaller than X** will be ignored and not returned to you.

**Confidence:** this is the *Disambiguation Confidence* parameter, it is a threshold which takes a value between 0 and 1. When you set a high value to it, **you get better and more trustworthy annotations** but you risk **losing some correct ones**.

Choosing values of those (or any other) parameters depends on your use case.

**Examples:**

- If you have some test set or gold standard for the type of n-grams you are interested in, you can tune your choice until you get good enough results satisfied by your gold standard.
- If you care about retrieving the top-N n-grams only to infer the topic of text, you can tune your parameters choosing high values to get few (mostly) correct n-grams and sort them by Confidence.
- If you want to get as many n-grams as possible and your task won't get affected or biased by mistakes, you can set low values.